# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined in Node Express / POST

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create an express but it seems that I cant pull the `req.body` in my `post`:

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.disable('x-powered-by')
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {})
})
app.post('/mobile/registration', (res, req, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.name)
});
```

Comment: Can you show the HTTP request that comes from the client? Or even just how you send the request?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's just a typo in your code or if you're not aware of it. But.. In the following code, i.e., in the `POST` request:

```
app.post('/mobile/registration', (res, req, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.name)
});
```

Observe `(res, req, next)` this part: You have given `req` after `res`. Even though you are trying to read `req.body`, what is named as `req` is actually the `res`(response).

Hence, interchange those to be `req` **before** `res`, like:

`(req, res, next)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this - Save this code as `sample.js`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express();    
 
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})) 
  app.use(bodyParser.json()) 

    app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
        res.render('index', {})
        })
  app.post('/mobile/registration', function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.body.name);
    res.json({status:true,Message:"Log Printed"})
 });
 var servers = app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("app started on port 3000");        
});
```

In terminal, run this file as node sample.js. Just follow the image to run api in postman [image]

In log it is printed as shown in below pic
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello. May I see what did console log in your program? Thank you

Comment: @jimSabandalx, the most evident glitch in your code is that you aren't starting the express server to listen on any particular port. I'm not sure if you've just missed including it in the question, if not.. Then first do fix it as Ayesha has done in the last part of her code.

Comment: @Rai yes may be it is one of the reason. And he unnecessarily added some special symbols in code

Comment: @jimSabandalx, add your full error response to the question. This should make it a bit easier to get to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

change `const app` to `var app` and try running your code. Sometimes using const and fix the value of app variable. I had run into a similar issue and resolved it this way.

Also if this is your only js file, you are not starting the express server to listen on any port.